# Hosting a Community

Tags: hosting

I have plans to start a new Community Website. I think the page will have 10,000 visits a day and 500-1000 Core People that visit the site regulary. Now : I'd like to have it as a service for the community. And I want to make it for the people and not for profit. How much does it cost to have a community like that?

I don't want to spend $2,000 / month for server hosting costs. It's fine when I make no money, but it's not fine when I have to pay more than $50 a month.

Comment: Send me an invite. =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at setting up a community on [Ning](http://www.ning.com/about-us/) - it's free.

Comment: That's exactly what Sysadmin-Network.com is set up on. Works decently enough.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to provide more information then "Community Website"

Do you want it to be like Facebook, like YouTube?  Do you want forums, pictures, profiles, a blog, a wiki?

You could likely use a hosting account with a company like GoDaddy for a low monthly fee (less then $20 a month) and the free apps they include with it (everything above) to put something together.

Answer (score 2):

If you have found the software that will power your community, the next thing you should focus on is **content caching**. Cache as much dynamic content as possible. Doing this part right, you will definitely spend less.